# How to discard certain messages from rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

A producer sends the message with routing key (x) to the exchange once in 5 secs. Based on the routing key, it is send to 2 queues A and B. The consumer which consumes from A wants it once in 5 secs , but the consumer that consumes from B needs the message only once in one min..

One way is to consume the messages from Queue B and discard the messages that we don't need(only considering once in one min) .

Is there any other better way for this to do in rabbitmq ?

Answer (score 0):

A consumer can keep state about the last time he consumed a message. When a new message arrives, can check if the the desired time has passed since the last message was consumed. If it wasn't, he can just ignore the message.

This is logic that must be handled by the consumer, not the RabbitMQ broker.

Answer (score 0):

The deduplication exchange of the [RMQ deduplication plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) has been designed to fit this purpose.

You can specify the time in which you don't want to see a similar message more than once and the exchange will drop any further copy of the given message. Messages are identified via the `x-deduplication-header`.

The amount of time a message is guaranteed to be unique can be controlled via the `x-cache-ttl` exchange argument or message header.